# Linearization of division between variables in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo

I need to formulate a constraint where a decision variable (a real number) is divided by another decision variable (an integer). This is obviously non-linear and I need a linear formulation.

Comment: Depends on the details. Note that not all non-linear models can be linearized (we would not need MINLP solvers if that was the case).

Comment: I'll give you the details ( expressed in Pyomo terms):
I have a real number sum_similarities[m] and an integer m_op_num[m], and I have to produce the result which is their division, let's call it division[m].
I saw this answer you posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752558/how-to-linearize-a-weighted-average-with-a-decision-variable
but my case seems much easier as I don't have binaries involved, how can I adapt it?
Bless you